Snowspeeder squad markings
I've just noticed the orange markings on the back end of a T-47 snowspeeder from Empire Strikes back. They're quite small, so they may get over looked.

It's part of five spaces, one orange, the other four are blank.
Could that be uses as identification similar to squad marking on the X-wing wings or were all snowspeeders the same?

Not definitive, but it doesn't look like there's any difference between markings in this shot: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/0/0a/Luke_leads_Rogue_Squadron.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/1000?cb=20091202204643
